# How can I install soap.so extension on debian with php5 and apache2?

Tags: php, soap, apache2, php-extension

I have a debian server with php5 in apache2 and I want to use soap extension.

I install soap extension with `# sudo apt-get install php-soap`,
I modify php.ini with `extension=php_soap.so`
and I reset apache.

But I check phpinfo and soap extension is not in `phpinfo`. Also, I have searched soap.so file on the server and it does not appear.

Thank you, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to find soap extension file and change your `extension_dir` with location dir of soap's `.so` file. Try to find it with **`locate soap`**. Also, may be you can point to your `.so` file like this and do not change `extension_dir`:

```
extension=/whateverlocation/soap.so
```

Comment: I have already searched and it does not be. I found a folder call SOAP with a php files(base.php, client.php, server.php...) but I execute a soap client over magento and I get the same error as before: SOAP extension is not loaded. Thank you

Comment: @majareta please try `sudo apt-get install php5-soap` and then show us what `locate soap` returns.

Comment: I did it, and I got the error _do not localize php5-soap packet_. I read in forums I could reinstall php with --enabled-soap, but I am novice with php and linux and I do not know how do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Finally, I did it [http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php)